# IP Masquerading in java

Tags: java, linux, http

I Have to get Data of users from different sites by sending a HttpRequest over the different URl in JAVA. One Problem what I am getting is that the requested URL blocks me after successive number of request that depends on URL to URL . The one solution to this problem is that I have to send request to same URL number of times by changing the IP every time the request is send . But I Have not having any idea to send the request by changing the IP over time to time IN Java.

I Have Tried with **IP Masquerading** but i could not found any tutorial for this step by step. I am new to this technology. I am trying this in linux(Fedora)

In java Please Help me in getting that.

Comment: Just a word of warning, if the sites block your requests, they'll probably have something in their Terms and Conditions that disallows what your trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

IP masquerading won't help you, it is used the other way around (usually so that private IP ranges can use public networks by masquerading behind one public IP). The problem you're having would require that you can use multiple public IP addresses.

Comment: How to do it? Is there step by step tutorial for this? Please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Well, you can't just get arbitrary public IPv4 addresses because they need to be assigned and routed to you. With IPv6 you could, however, the service you're accessing as well as your provider and router would need to be using IPv6, all of which is currently rarely in place.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have data incoming from several users. What you could try to do as a workaround is  have the request to the blocked URL done from the client side, so from the user's IP address. Then send the result to your server and use it there.